# kivy dropdown menu in FloatLayout and GridLayout doesnt show up

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, kivy, dropdown

Hey guys trying to create an app with a dropdown button but it seems to not work (the full app has GridLayout with 7 rows and this FloatLayout in the example is one of the rows) I've tried with GridLayout, BoxLayout, and FloatLayout and still doesn't appear on the app. Any ideas what's wrong here?

.py file

```
class WindowManager(ScreenManager, Screen):
    TestMe = ObjectProperty(None)

text_lists = ['hi', 'nice one', 'another one']


class TestMe(Screen, FloatLayout):
    global text_lists
    main_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    selected_list = 'SELECTED'
    top_layout = ObjectProperty(None)
    top_layout = GridLayout(cols=4)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestMe, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dropdown = DropDown()
        self.create_drop_down()
        self.create_go_button()

    def create_drop_down(self):
        for list_name in text_lists:
            # When adding widgets, we need to specify the height manually
            # (disabling the size_hint_y) so the dropdown can calculate
            # the area it needs.

            btn = Button(text= list_name, size_hint_y=None, height=88, width=400, background_color=(41/255, 21/255, 228/255, 1))

            # for each button, attach a callback that will call the select() method
            # on the dropdown. We'll pass the text of the button as the data of the
            # selection.
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(btn.text),
                     on_press=lambda btn: self.select_list(btn.text))

            # then add the button inside the dropdown
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)

        # create a big main button
        self.main_button = Button(text='Choose A List', size_hint=(None, None), height=88, width=400, background_color=(41/255, 21/255, 228/255, 1))

        # show the dropdown menu when the main button is released
        # note: all the bind() calls pass the instance of the caller (here, the
        # mainbutton instance) as the first argument of the callback (here,
        # dropdown.open.).
        self.main_button.bind(on_release=self.dropdown.open)

        # one last thing, listen for the selection in the dropdown list and
        # assign the data to the button text.
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(self.main_button, 'text', x))
        self.top_layout.add_widget(self.main_button)

    def create_go_button(self):
        go_btn = Button(text="Go!", size_hint=(None, None), height=88, width=400, background_color=(41/255, 21/255, 228/255, 1))
        self.top_layout.add_widget(go_btn)

    def select_list(self, selected):
        self.selected_list = selected

class MyTest(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kv = Builder.load_file('test_kv.kv')

    MyTest().run()
```

test_kv.kv file

```
WindowManager:
    TestMe:

<TestMe>:
name: "testy"
id: testy
top_layout: top_layout
FloatLayout:
    Label:
        text: 'Test Screen'
        font: 'Aharoni'
        font_size: 24
        pos_hint: {"left": 0.45, "y": 0.45}
    GridLayout:
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.9}
        size_hint: 1, 0.8
        rows: 2
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        GridLayout:
            id: top_layout
            cols: 4
            Button:
                text: "Fun!"
            Label:
                text: "This is a test"
        Button:
            text: "Run!"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `create_drop_down()` and `create_go_button()` in the `__init__()` method of the `TestMe` class. Since you also define a `<TestMe>:` rule in your `kv`, there is a conflict. According to the somewhat unclear [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#order-of-kwargs-and-kv-rule-application), the `kv` rule is applied after the `__init__()` is run. That means that any `Widgets` added to `TestMe` in its `__init__()` will be overwritten by the `Widegets` specified in the `kv` rule. The possible solutions are to add all the children of `TestMe` in either the `__init__()` method or in the `kv`, or to move the adding of `Widgets` out of the `__init__()` method. Here is a modified version of your code that does the latter approach:

```
class WindowManager(ScreenManager, Screen):
    TestMe = ObjectProperty(None)

text_lists = ['hi', 'nice one', 'another one']


class TestMe(Screen, FloatLayout):
    global text_lists
    main_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    selected_list = 'SELECTED'
    top_layout = ObjectProperty(None)
    #top_layout = GridLayout(cols=4)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestMe, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dropdown = DropDown()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_drop_down)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_go_button)
        # self.create_drop_down()
        # self.create_go_button()

    def create_drop_down(self, *args):
        for list_name in text_lists:
            # When adding widgets, we need to specify the height manually
            # (disabling the size_hint_y) so the dropdown can calculate
            # the area it needs.

            btn = Button(text= list_name, size_hint_y=None, height=88, width=400, background_color=(41/255, 21/255, 228/255, 1))

            # for each button, attach a callback that will call the select() method
            # on the dropdown. We'll pass the text of the button as the data of the
            # selection.
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(btn.text),
                     on_press=lambda btn: self.select_list(btn.text))

            # then add the button inside the dropdown
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)

        # create a big main button
        # self.main_button = Button(text='Choose A List', size_hint=(None, None), height=88, width=400, background_color=(41/255, 21/255, 228/255, 1))
        self.main_button = Button(text='Choose A List', background_color=(41/255, 21/255, 228/255, 1))

        # show the dropdown menu when the main button is released
        # note: all the bind() calls pass the instance of the caller (here, the
        # mainbutton instance) as the first argument of the callback (here,
        # dropdown.open.).
        self.main_button.bind(on_release=self.dropdown.open)

        # one last thing, listen for the selection in the dropdown list and
        # assign the data to the button text.
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(self.main_button, 'text', x))
        self.top_layout.add_widget(self.main_button)

    def create_go_button(self, *args):
        # go_btn = Button(text="Go!", size_hint=(None, None), height=88, width=400, background_color=(41/255, 21/255, 228/255, 1))
        go_btn = Button(text="Go!", background_color=(41/255, 21/255, 228/255, 1))
        self.top_layout.add_widget(go_btn)

    def select_list(self, selected):
        self.selected_list = selected

class MyTest(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv
```

I have modified the code to call the `create` methods using `Clock.schedule_once()`, so that it happens after the `kv` rule is applied.
I have also removed the `size_hint` and `size`  arguments to the `Buttons` created to allow the `GridLayout` to size them. I have also commented out some unnecessary code.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is it!

Answer (score 0):

The big main button appears when I run your code (had to add an `App` class), and works as expected. But the `Button` appears in the lower left corner with your `light.png` `Image`. Try moving it a bit so it doesn't overlap that `Image`. Something like this:

```
    self.main_button = Button(text='Choose A List', size_hint=(None, None), height=88, width=140,
                              background_color=(41/255, 21/255, 228/255, 1), pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'y':0.4})
```

I also made it a bit wider to contain the `Choose A List` text.

Comment: hi, I've tried it now as well but the same result, (I have another app which I did the same and it worked, very strange) what else can it be?

Comment: Do you see the 'Choose A List' `Button` in your GUI?

Comment: No, only the light button and the label

Comment: I've now noticed that the problem is because of the "add_widget", seems it's not working for me from python (tried to add the light button and label from there but that way they don't show up) any clue what to do?

Comment: Keep in mind that the default size hint is `(1,1)` and the default position is `(0,0`, so adding `Widgets` without adjusting these values may result in added `Widgets` being on top of each other and hiding previously added `Widgets`.

Comment: Yes but the GridLayout I'm trying to add is actually GridLayout inside GridLayout (so no need to add those (?)

Comment: Since you didn't provide a [mcve], I had to edit your code just to get something that runs. That leads me to believe that there is something else going on that is not in the code you provided. Please edit your post to make it a [mcve].